# How can I hide my C-library code while debuging

Tags: c, stm32, iar, stm32f4

I want to create my C-function as library and I want to hide my code from every one

I want to every one cannot see C/Assemble code while debugging.

So I use IAR for create a C-library file and set **Project → Option** as below

- General Option → Output → Output file : **Library**
- General Option → Library Configuration → Library: **None**
- C/C++ Compiler → Output: **[Unchecked] Generate debug information**
- Assembler → Output: **[Unchecked] Generate debug information**

After that I use library that I created and try debug. I can see my library as assemble code but I don't want it.

**So How can I hide it.**

> Example:

I created a sample function

**Library Project**

```
#include "mylib.h"
#include "stdint.h"

int64_t my_add(int64_t a, int64_t b)
{
  return a+b;    
}
```

**Application Project**

```
add_result = my_add(10, 20);  /* I debug at this line */
```

After code run to the debug point, I press F11 (step into). Debug is able to jump to my libary code show in picture below.
[image: Debuging is able to see my code as assemble]

Comment: You should ask to IAR support. BTW I think you cannot hide your compiled code, as far as that code is loaded on the target it is reachable and readable.

Comment: Unless you're using a cryptographic processor, you won't be able to hide assembly code: if the processor can read it, so users could.

Comment: There are several tools, e.g. `ptrace`, that can track library calls without a debugger.  Compiling code is not a form of encryption, only obfuscation.

Comment: @LPs I asked them 4 days ago but they not reply me a answer yet.

Comment: Some people write code to detect debugging and finish program in that case, other people modifying debugging techniques to be undetectable

Comment: The only thing that you can really do is enable read protection, however this is a global on/off flag and cannot be changed in per-sector manner like write protection. This also however won't allow you to debug the program at all. As far as I'm aware, there's no way of doing what you're trying to achieve on stm32 - if one can view the assembly of one section of the flash, so can be viewed the rest of the flash contents.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to strip **ALL symbols** from the output file. You need to ask IAR how to do this. Then "*my_add*" and "*my_sub*" would not be there. The debugger will read the binary code and translate to assembler depending on the architecture used, so of course you cannot get rid of this.

Comment: great, lets see what they say. Probably they have something similar to the --strip-all flag (gnu utilities)

Comment: even if you strip all the symbols from the file, you'll still be able to read the output assembly. [Obfuscating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obfuscation) the code might make [reverse engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_engineering) a bit more difficult but it's no way unreadable. If the CPU can execute the instructions, so can a person and vice versa